# Dealing with errors during a copy from

Tags: postgresql

I've to import a file from an external source to a postgresql table.
I tried to do it with \copy from , but I keep getting errors (additional columns) in the middle of the file.

Is there a way to tell postgresql to ignore lines containing errors during a "\copy from" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try with [PostgreSQL Loader](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader) instead.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll give pgloader a try.

Answer (score 1):

No. All data is correct or there is no data at all, those are the two options you have in PostgreSQL.